# MiniDisplay Port Adapaters

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, amd-radeon, displayport

I just bought a new video card, a Radeon 7870.  Quite excited.  Problem is it has 1 DVI, 1 HDMI and 2 Mini DisplayPort ports.  I have three monitors.  High end IPS panels, 1920X1080 resolution.  What is the best way to connect these three monitors to my new graphics card?

For inputs, the monitors have 1 HDMI, 1 regular DisplayPort, 1 DVI and 1 VGA.
At the moment I could get two to work, 1 through DVI and 1 through HDMI, though I hate mixing standards like that.  My other thought would be to get 1 or 2 Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapters and run all 3 monitors off of DVI to keep things standard.

Other suggestions?  Is there an inherent advantage of say a Mini DP to DP adapter vs a Mini DP to DVI?

Comment: If I fits I sits. Else look into purchasing adapters.

Answer (score 0):

To use three monitors with [AMD Eyefinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyefinity#Multi-display_technologies) at least one of them has to use the display port (either mini or full). This table is in the wikipedia article for 5800 cards but I am pretty sure it applies to the 6450 as well:

[image: table]

If you don't have a monitor with display port as an input you can get an active DisplayPort to DVI-D adapter. I have a 6950 with my main monitor using HDMI one side monitor using DVI-D and the other using this [adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004071ZXA) to DVI. It works very nice the only downside being that occasionally when I wake the computer from sleep the monitor on the adapter doesn't wake up. If I unplug and replug the adapter it works.